# About phpmyadmin

Tags: phpmyadmin

I am using phpmyadmin for my database purpose.Myisam is my database engine.
I want to know about what is mean about:"choose field to display" in relationship page in phpmyadmin

Comment: Siraj, no downvote though haven't you searched [phpMyAdmin official docs](http://www.phpmyadmin.net/home_page/docs.php)..?

Comment: The folks at webmasters.se would be able to answer your question. StackOverflow are for questions related to programming only. No action on your part is required, this question will be migrated over *by magic*.

Answer (score 1):

I can't find anything about this in the documentation, but I expect, from other databases I've used, that it is asking you which field to display from the second table when listing the first table.

For example if table 1 is people and it has a field "country code". If table 2 is a list of codes and countries, and you set up a relationship between the two. If you choose the country name to display, then when table 1 is listed instead of displaying the country code it will display the country name for that country code.